# <p:dataTable> each column needs to be uniquely identified

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying some thing like this:
I have a piece of code, where in a  a list of values are displayed.

```
<h:panelGroup id="table-wrapper">
    <p:dataTable value="#{searchBean.listUser}" var="user" rendered="#{not empty searchBean.listUser}" style="width: 10%;">
        <p:column headerText="Trigram">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.strUserid}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="First Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.strFirstname}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Last Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.strLastname}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Insert PL">
            <p:commandLink actionListener="#{searchBean.getRowDetails}" id="plValue" process="@this" title="Insert Leave">
                <h:graphicImage url="resources/images/button.png" style="height: 10px;width:10px"/>
                <f:attribute name="tri" value="#{user.strUserid}"/>
                <f:attribute name="fname" value="#{user.strFirstname}"/>
                <f:attribute name="lname" value="#{user.strLastname}"/>
            </p:commandLink>                                            
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Here, the `actionListener` does not fire when the button is clicked? The codes are within the `<h:form>` tag.

Using JDK6.0 | Jboss As 7.1.1 final | JSF2.0 | PrimeFaces 3.4.2

Comment: using `<h:commandButton>` does not open the page `./insertLeave.xhtml` and not even fires the actionListener weirdly?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the example in the Primefaces showcase of instant row selection, where the selected row is displayed in a dialog? If you really need a button, then you can use a commandbutton to set the selectedItem in the backing bean and an oncomplete to show a dialog in the same way

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf